# Recommendation for engineering mathematics textbook

Tags: education, book-recommendation

I will be teaching a two semester introductory course in engineering mathematics next year at an applied university. This course will be given in English for the first time and I'm currently looking for a nice textbook as a reference for the students. Topics will be basic calculus in one and several variables, basic ordinary differential equations, complex numbers, computations with vectors and matrices, and linear systems of equations. Can anyone recommend a book?

Comment: How about Erwin Kreyszig Advanced Engineering Mathematics?

Comment: Kreyszig is too advanced. It directly starts with ODEs. I need something more elementary, covering basic limits and also an introduction to differentiation and integration.

Comment: K.A Stroud's "Engineering Mathematics" looks interesting to me. Has anybody used this book?

Answer (score 0):

A good book in German language is [Mathematik für Ingenieure](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642542893) by Westermann 
Lothar Papula's books (German) are also good .
Unfortunately I have not yet found a similar book in English.
If you know of any, let me know. I am also interested in a similar material. ([See](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2655818/353218))