# Book recommendation: Mathematics for Engineers

Tags: self-learning, education, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book similar to this [Mathematik für Ingenieure](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642542893) however in English.

Which through various exercises and applicable examples addresses the bacic math knowledge that an Engineer should have. For example:

- *IntegVectors and matrices*
- *Complex numbers*
- *Differential calculus*
- *Real calculus for functions with multiple variables*
- *Fourier-Transformation*
  -etc..

At Amazon I find many books with a good rating according to "Engineering Mathematics", but I'm not sure if these books are really good

Could someone - with experience in this kind of books - make me a recommendation?
Thank!

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic. You might try looking at the Cambridge website and see if you can find useful material related to the Engineering Tripos. The MIT website might be helpful as well; they put lots of their course material on line.

Answer (score 3):

While not a complete answer, you can check out my differential equations textbook which is aimed at engineers: *Notes on Diffy Qs: Differential Equations for Engineers*, https://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/ I created it for the differential equations course at University of Illinois Urbana-Champaign, which is a big engineering school, and I'd say about 95% of the students in that course were engineers.

I am not sure if there is a single book that does all that you want.  You probably need to pick up a variety of books.  I'd suggest picking up a few basic textbooks such as the one above and calculus for the basic background.  You might also check out *The Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics* (look for it on amazon).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ["Engineering Mathematics" by K.A. Stroud](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Engineering-Mathematics-K-Stroud/dp/1137031204/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1540747780&sr=8-1&keywords=engineering+mathematics).

If this isnt enough try his "Advanced Engineering Mathematics"